# Two user types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase

I am trying to make an app with two different user types. There are two different home screens I want to route to depending on the type of user is logging in. I am not able to do this with either user type to their respective home screen.

EDIT: updated code

```
@IBAction func signInButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //check if email and password fields are filled and TODO- valid
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text {
        //sign in user with Firebase
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { (user, error) in
            //check that user is not nil
            if user != nil {

                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                self.ref.child("Users").child(userID!).child("accountType").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in

                    if let accountType = Snapshot.value as? String{

                        // You have retrieved the account type
                        // Now Segue

                        if accountType == "user1"{

                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome1", sender: self)


                        }
                        if accountType == "user2"{

                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome2", sender: self)

                        }
                        else{
                            print("Error1")
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        print("Error2")

                        // There was no node found in the database
                        // named 'accountType'
                    }
                }
            )}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening?  Have you set breakpoints at your `if let accountType =` line to check that you actually stepping inside that code block?

Comment: it is stepping inside that code block when I try that. When the user taps the sign in button, nothing happens. It stays on the sign in view.

Comment: and you have double checked that you have segues from your `SignInViewController` to your other VCs using those identifiers?  Add `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {` and add `print(segue.identifier)`

Comment: Yes, I double checked the segue identifiers and they are correct. Where do I put the override function?

Comment: I get error2 when I run the updated code above, so I am not correctly identifying the node. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Bob Can you paste your database structure and snapshot output?

Comment: @ZassX Here is the database structure: http://imgur.com/a/kPuF6 and the only output when the user signs in is "Error2"

Comment: @Bob print out userID. You will see that it doesn't match anything in your `Users` node because UID's are generated a bit differently than database keys. What you need to do is change `$userKey` node under `Users` to match user ID.

Comment: @ZassX, sorry, I am a novice at this. How can I do this?

Comment: @Bob just print out user UID you get from `auth().currentUser?.uid` and see if you have any entry with that in database. If not, this is the problem

Comment: @ZassX you are right, the UID is not something that is in my database. This was the output: Optional("WE7D5lwHuyRj1X9FcoSg3dvF0Rf1")  How do I call the appropriate key?

Comment: @Bob when you are saving user data into database, don't use `.childByAutoId()`(you are probably using it) to generate key but instead use `userId`. Please UPDATE question with your database structure link and paste function where you save user into database so I can help you solve this.